# What are the differences between Daisy and Peach in Super Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

So, I’m pretty sure that Daisy is pretty much a complete clone of Peach, but for free, and takes a far longer time to unlock. Are there any differences between the two? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://www.gamezebo.com/2017/09/29/unlock-daisy-super-mario-run/), this is one difference between Daisy and Peach.

> Daisy looks like Princess Peach but has a double-jump ability instead of hover

Comment: I just unlocked her.